# Python - Why are some lines in a text file being ordered by time and others by letter?

Tags: python, text-files

```
count = len(open('times.txt').readlines())
if fighter2.visible == False:
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end - begin
    elapsed = round(elapsed, 2)
    elapsed = str(elapsed)
    print('\nWell done! You completed the game in', elapsed, 'seconds.\nCheck the leaderboard to see where you placed.')
    with open ('times.txt','a') as f:
        f.write(name)
        f.write('          ')
        f.write(elapsed)
        f.write('\n')

    with open ('times.txt','r') as f:
        readthefile = f.readlines()
        sortedData = sorted(readthefile,reverse = True)
        
    print('\n')
    for line in range(count + 1):
        print(str(line + 1) + '\t' + str(sortedData[line]))
```

here is the code I am using to order times in a text file. So far only the top 3 lines of the file are being ordered by time and after that the lines are ordered alphabetically by their name instead of the time.

Comment: Can you give us sample input file `times.txt`?

Comment: what does this gotta do with pygame?

Comment: Without seeing more, I'm betting on a "why is the order 1, 10, 2, 3..." kind of question

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your iterating ***elapsed*** 3 times when you count to 2 (0, 1, 2) so first 3 lines will be numbers.
- Next line your iterating ***str*** which is why your getting an alphabet for the rest.

Consider ***while true*** statements